# DDL query with CLOB data type

Tags: oracle

In oracle database, execution of following query fails:

```
CREATE TABLE ADMIN.TESTCLOB (
      "testclobcolumn" CLOB(2147483647)
)
```

whereas following query works:

```
CREATE TABLE ADMIN.TESTCLOB (
      "testclobcolumn" CLOB
)
```

What's the reason for it? When I see that CLOB columns allows passing length parameter https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLOB doesn't accept any parameter in Oracle database.

Documentation you read is related to *Derby* (click the link at the bottom of page whose link you posted, it leads here: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/crefsqlj31068.html which says "This section describes the data types used in Derby."

I suggest you read documentation related to Oracle itself, e.g. Oracle 12c Data Types (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021).

(I intentionally posted links as they are, so that you'd see the difference).

---

What is Derby, then? Here are [Difference between Oracle and Derby](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-oracle-and-derby/); Google for more.